# SQL to find gaps in date ranges in Netezza

Tags: sql, netezza, gaps-and-islands

I would like to get the gaps between date range and needed it to separate the gaps by MM ID.

could you please someone help me to resolve below in Netezza

**INPUT:**

```
ID | MM Number | From | To 

12345|4444444 |2015-01-03 |2015-02-02 

12346|4444444 |2015-02-03 |2015-03-02
```

<< missing one record ( ex same MM Number no record for period from 2015-03-03 to 2015-04-02

```
12347|4444444 |2015-04-03 |2015-05-01 

12348|4444444 |2015-05-02 |2015-06-01 

12349|4444444 |2015-06-02 |2015-07-01 

12310|4444444 |2015-07-02 |2015-07-31
```

<< missing one record (ex: same MM Number no record for period from 2015-08-01 to 2015-08-31

```
12310|4444444|2015-09-01|2015-09-30
```

**Expected Out put:**

```
MM No | Missing Start Date | Missing To Date 
4444444 |2015-03-03 |2015-04-02 
4444444 |2015-08-01 |2015-08-31
```

I've a table with below data

```
create table icr_tmp 
( 
ID VARCHAR2(15), 
NMI VARCHAR2(50), 
INVOICE_START_DATE DATE, 
INVOICE_END_DATE DATE); 

insert into icr_tmp values('12345','4444444','03/01/2015','02/02/2015'); 

insert into icr_tmp values('12346','4444444','03/02/2015','02/03/2015'); 

insert into icr_tmp values('12347','4444444','03/04/2015','01/05/2015'); 

insert into icr_tmp values('12348','4444444','02/05/2015','01/06/2015'); 

insert into icr_tmp values('12349','4444444','02/06/2015','01/07/2015'); 

insert into icr_tmp values('12310','4444444','02/07/2015','31/07/2015'); 

insert into icr_tmp values('12310','4444444','01/09/2015','30/09/2015');
```

Below SQL working in oracle perfectly but not in Netezza.

```
select * 
from (
  select nmi,max(invoice_end_date) over(partition by nmi order by invoice_start_date) + 1 start_gap,
    lead(invoice_start_date) over(partition by nmi order by invoice_start_date) - 1 end_gap
  from icr_tmp3
)
where start_gap <= end_gap;

NMI      START_GAP   END_GAP

4444444  2015-03-03  2015-04-02

4444444  2015-08-01  2015-08-31
```

How do I change the above SQL to run in Netezza?

Answer (score 0):

Your query should work perfectly fine on netezza, only thing missing i saw is alias to the subquery, as netezza will complain if subqueries are not aliased.

```
select * 
from (
  select nmi
  ,max(invoice_end_date) over(partition by nmi order by invoice_start_date) + 1 start_gap,
  lead(invoice_start_date) over(partition by nmi order by invoice_start_date) - 1 end_gap  
  from icr_tmp
) foo
where start_gap <= end_gap;
```